# Can't find PhpStorm

Tags: installation, command-line, unity-dash

I am new, never used Ubuntu until yesterday, so I'm not really into it, yet. I installed PhpStorm from JetBrains, but I can't find it anywhere, I need to run it.
I searched `/usr/share/applications` as suggested in another post, but again, no success.

Please give a helping hand. Any terminal command or help with the location I could find it and make a shortcut on the desktop would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you install?

Comment: According to the installation guide in the answer

I worked with phpstorm a little bit and then closed it.
Now I don't know where to find it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This tutorial can be helpful for what you need: [Running PHPStorm](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Installing_and_running_PHPStorm_on_Ubuntu#Running_PHPStorm).

Run the following commands in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```
cd /home/user/PHPStorm/PhpStorm-111.296/bin
chmod +x phpstorm.sh
./phpstorm.sh
```

You can create a shortcut on the Desktop by using `gnome-desktop-item-edit` in terminal as follow (note that if you don't have installed the package `gnome-desktop-item-edit`, you must be install first, so if you have `gnome-shell` or `gnome-tweak-tool` installed, then it is installed automatically):

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```

This will start the dialog (Create Launcher):

[image]

Insert for **Name** any name you want (for example 'PHPStorm') and for **Command** `sh /home/user/PHPStorm/PhpStorm-111.296/bin/phpstorm.sh` and press **Ok**.

You can put this `.desktop` file in any folder, and then drag and drop to the Launcher.

<sup>Thanks to [Binarylife](https://askubuntu.com/users/4937/binarylife) for [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/78968/147044).</sup>

Comment: It is exactly what I did. But after I ran phpstorm, I closed it. Now I can't find it. I guess I don't always need to run that in order to launch PhpStorm after installation

Comment: Open again PhpStorm from terminal with this command: `/home/user/PHPStorm/PhpStorm-111.296/bin//phpstorm.sh`. After it will open, right click on it on Launcher and select *Lock on Launcher*.

Comment: I locked it to the launcher but it does not launch

Comment: @BujancaMihai I edited my answer, check now.

Answer (score 6):

I faced similar problem. You can solve this as

```
1. First locate your phpstorm.sh using command:  locate -b phpstorm.sh
2. Copy these url
2. For Running phpstorm: sudo [paste these url] 
3. For solving this problem permanently use Radu Rădeanu's answer,given     
at top.
```

Comment: And if you get `command not found: locate`, then run this: `sudo apt-get install mlocate`

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but I had the exact same problem which brought me here, however I found the answer in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28555/how-to-find-applications-path-from-command-line).

The short answer which worked for me: open the terminal and type the following at the command prompt: `locate -b WebStorm`

Answer (score 1):

If the software is installed with **ubuntu software center**, its likely using snap and the downloaded src files can be found at **/snap/phpstorm**

Comment: Yep, I installed PhpStorm with snap like "sudo snap install phpstorm --classic" and it was installed into "/snap/phpstorm"

Answer (score 0):

I located phpstorm and the starting script phpstorm.sh on my Debian Stretch system using this shell cmd:

```
sudo find / -name "phpstorm*"
```

Output:

```
...
/opt/PhpStorm-172.3968.35/bin/phpstorm.sh
...
```